# Online Learning/Continual Learning for tree-based Algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, xgboost, lightgbm, online-learning

Every example I come across any kind of *iterative learning* on *Random Forest/XGBoost/LightGBM*, it just continuously grows the number of estimators for new batches of data by `n_tree`/`n_estimators`/`num_boost_rounds` every time `.fit()` gets applied [...]. Most of them seem to rely on iterative learning for training on very large datasets that can't be loaded into memory at once.

However, I want to implement a continuous learning pipeline (with LightGBM; Python) that takes newly available data on a daily basis in order to update an existing model (without the need to retrain on the whole [growing] dataset; stateful). The initially mentioned approach would imply that my model will ever increase its tree count.

**Is it possible to train tree-based algorithms so that the estimators (split thresholds) themselves get updated/adjusted in contrast to only adding estimators?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really good question for which I will give you a theoretical result; in particular, I am not aware of any specific implementation in any programming language.

The concept of *incremental* learning with decision trees started in 1986 to enhance the ID3 learning algorithm to learn continually/incrementally (recall that ID3 deals only with categorical input features/variables); the resulting procedure is called [ID4](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/1986/AAAI86-083.pdf).

Some years later, Utgoff et al. proposed other two approaches ([ID5](https://people.cs.umass.edu/%7Eutgoff/papers/mlj-id5r.pdf) and [ITI](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.4.786&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) to overcome some of the shortcomings of the ID4 approach.

There is also a nice Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_decision_tree) that you might read.

**EDIT**

There are also works on [online boosting and bagging](http://proceedings.mlr.press/r3/oza01a/oza01a.pdf), which I was not aware of either, but your question thought me something new; thanks for that (+1)!

Comment: Highly appreciate your feedback! Your answer also reminded me of the concept of 'Hoeffding [Decision] Trees' as predecessor of EFDT ('Extremely Fast Decision Tree'; as mentioned in the linked Wikipedia article) - although they assume a static data distribution over time. An implementation of Hoeffding Trees for Regreesion can be found in scikit-multiflow (https://scikit-multiflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) for stream processing. I have to wrap my head around, whether this is a viable approach for my particular problem. I'll leave the question open for now - thank you!

Comment: Yes, you are right, I also wanted to say something about those two. I just wanted to keep things as simple as possible as both research papers are very technical; although, are very good reading. I appreciate that there are implementations, and this is an opportunity for my research team and I to enhance such implementations with different degrees of expressivity (+1 to your comment).